# Is calling auth0 hook to verify authentication in all my Custom React Hook a good approach?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, react-hooks, graphql

I have a single-page app where I build multiples Custom React Hook to fetch data in my backend (MongoDB). Every time, I'm also verifying if the user is logged before fetching data like so:

```js
export const useTotalSessionsToday = () => {
  const { user } = useAuth0();
  let userName;
  if (user) {
    userName = user.name;
  }

  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_TOTAL_SESSIONS_TODAY, {
    variables: { userName },
  });

  return { data, loading, error };
};
```

Currently, I'm calling the auth0 hook in every Custom Hook. I find it hard to believe there isn't a better way (since calling auth0 hook is somehow slow).

Should I use localStorage and store the user "username" on page load and then fetch it from there instead? Or is it still better to call auth0 every time?

PS: I use Typescript with React and Graphql

Comment: You need to verify the user is logged in, but you can cache the authentication, which is typically (and ideally) slow, as well as any other data you want. What are you using on the backend? You probably want to find some sort of package that will handle sessions.

Comment: I'm using GraphQL with ApolloServer/Express that fetch into my MongoDB (with mongoose) database. I wonder if I can authenticate in the backend directly instead of sending the "username" from the front-end.

Comment: Maybe look into [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session), which creates a session middleware in Express. You would authenticate the user normally in the initial request, and then in subsequent requests, the user would simply send the session cookie to the server with the session ID, so you do not have to re-authenticate them.

Comment: Ah I see. So the correct way is to store the session in the backend to avoid re-authenticating every time, right?

Comment: Yes, all of the actual session data is stored in the backend so that it can't be modified by the user. The user only gets the session ID.